# add Objects in a bidemensional arrayList of size unknow JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

i'm trying to add a element in an arrayList that is inside a arraylist, 
when i had elements before i used to get a element by putting

```
ListName.get(index1).get(index2);
```

and it returns to me whatever is inside this coordenates

i'm trying to add objects while my biArrayList is empty, so i have this:

```
private List<List<Cadeira>> lista = new ArrayList<List<Cadeira>>();
lista.get(0).add(myObject);
```

however i'm getting in a exception because my position 0 does not exist yet

any ideia on how to solve this??
ty in advance

Comment: You're going to have to add an empty list in at position 0 explicitly.  There's no real way around that.  You're going to have to write e.g. `lista.add(new ArrayList<Cadeira>())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the list first with a constructor. Do

```
lista.add(new ArrayList<Cadeira>());
lista.get(0).add(myObject);
```

Comment: Well, you can't access `lista.get(lista.size())` because ArrayList is indexed like an array. Array of length n is 0...n - 1, ArrayList is the same. So you must say `lista.get(lista.size() - 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your lista is empty list. You have to add a Cadeira List into it.

```
List<List<Cadeira>> lista = new ArrayList<List<Cadeira>>();  // declares and initializes a list contains object Cadeira List object, but the list is empty
List<Cadeira> listc = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add(listc);
```

Now you can invoke `lista.get(0).add(myObject)`

Alternatively, you can use

```
listc.add(myObject);
```